# How to check which applications are active via my aplication IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I must to know how can I check if some applications are working via my application and if it's possible to check that and if I can check moment wwhen user turn on application and turn off it and which applications works at this moment and if phone is turn on and using or no. I need some code to write application. thanks for help. sorry for my english.

Comment: You can't monitor whether other apps are running or not this goes against Apple rules. Also Apps work in a sandboxed mode so don't even now about other apps, so this isn't possible.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible Apps in iOS work in a sandboxed mode so they don't know about other applications on or running on the the device so you can't monitor other apps. Please have a read of the Apple Documentation in regards to [App Sandox Design](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html).

Also this sort of thing would be rejected from the Apple Review process under rule

> 2.6 - Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected

Due to you reading other apps data usage which is outside of the designated container.